# Grouping + row difference? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do this? I have this table

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ITEM   ║ PRICE    ║ DATE     ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ Dollar ║       60 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      100 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      600 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Output should display one item from each type with last price dedepnding on last date and price difference from previous row, like this

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ ITEM   ║ PRICE    ║ DATE     ║ Differnece  ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║   -10       ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║    10       ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║   -20       ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

this is what I did but it is throwing error

```
SELECT a.item, a.price, a.date, a.price - b.price AS difference
FROM (SELECT t1.item, t1.price, t1.date
      FROM yourTable AS t1
      JOIN (SELECT item, MAX(date) AS maxdate
            FROM yourTable
            GROUP BY item) AS t2
      ON t1.item = t2.item, t1.date = t2.maxdate) AS a
JOIN (SELECT t1.item, t1.price, t1.date
      FROM yourTable AS t1
      JOIN (SELECT item, MIN(date) AS mindate
            FROM yourTable
            GROUP BY item) AS t2
      ON t1.item = t2.item, t1.date = t2.mindate) AS b
```

This is the error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.maxdate) AS a JOIN (SELECT t1.item_type, t1.purchasing_price, t1.date_price ' at line 7

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us your code.

Comment: not really, i am not really a programmer

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a real programmer. You can't expect to come here and get us to do it every time you need a query written.

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery to get the first row for each item, and another subquery to get the last row for each item, join them and subtract.

```
SELECT a.item, a.price, a.date, a.price - b.price AS difference
FROM (SELECT t1.item, t1.price, t1.date
      FROM yourTable AS t1
      JOIN (SELECT item, MAX(date) AS maxdate
            FROM yourTable
            GROUP BY item) AS t2
      ON t1.item = t2.item, t1.date = t2.maxdate) AS a
JOIN (SELECT t1.item, t1.price, t1.date
      FROM yourTable AS t1
      JOIN (SELECT item, MIN(date) AS mindate
            FROM yourTable
            GROUP BY item) AS t2
      ON t1.item = t2.item, t1.date = t2.mindate) AS b
```

Comment: I get this error
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.maxdate AS a JOIN (SELECT t1.item_type, t1.purchasing_price, t1.date_price ' at line 7

Comment: Looks like you left out the `)` after `t2.maxdate`.

Comment: Click on the Jobs button and post a job listing.

Comment: I don't want a full time programmer, I just want to do this, mysql table to xml. Just one query!

Comment: I gave you the answer for this query.

Comment: My point about hiring a programmer was a suggestion for the future, since this is unlikely to be the last time you'll need a query written.